# Is it possible to add Spring tag in HTML file?

Tags: html, spring

I have a HTML file (not JSP) and want to use . So I added

```
   <%@ page prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springfreamework.org/tags"%>
```

on the top of the HTML file. 
However an warning sing comes out.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sure you can add it, will it do something no it won't.

Answer (score 0):

The answes is no. You can't add spring library to html.
But you can use thymeleaf and add such libraries (not that but similar) to html and use jsp advantages in html.